# Algorithm 'xgboost' is not registered

Tags: r, xgboost, h2o

I am running the following snippet of code

```
h2o_xgb <- h2o.xgboost(x = features, 
                       y = response, 
                       training_frame = train,
                       nfolds = 3)
h2o_xgb
```

I am getting the following error

```
Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  : 
  

ERROR MESSAGE:

Algorithm 'xgboost' is not registered. Available algos: [targetencoder,deeplearning,glm,glrm,kmeans,naivebayes,pca,svd,drf,gbm,isolationforest,aggregator,word2vec,stackedensemble,coxph,generic,gam,psvm,rulefit]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if xgboost is available on the h2o cluster and can be used with:

`h2o.xgboost.available()`

But if you are on Windows xgboost within h2o is not available. See [the limitations](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/xgboost.html#limitations) on help pages of h2o for xgboost.